# How to merge multiple Excel files into a single one using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The goal it to loop through multiple excel files in Blob Storage and load data into a single excel file using Data Factory Copy activity. Seems pretty simple.

However, I could not find any example of merging multiple Excel files into a single excel using Data Factory.

I was able to find lots of examples of how to merge multiple .cvs files, parquet files etc. But not Excel.

I tried to achieve that by using a Copy Activity, however when creating a Sink dataset, I cannot see Excel format.

So why there is no Excel format?
What would be a workaround for it?

Comment: IIRC, Excel is not a supported Sink type because it has a hard ceiling for row and column count and is unworkable at the scale for most use cases which it makes sense to use a tool like ADF in the first place. What does Excel’s format give you that CSV (DelimitedText) does not?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately ADF doesn't support excel format in sink. So in order to achieve your goal, you would have to use custom code via azure function or azure batch etc